# How to get compartment ID by name in Terraform OCI

Tags: terraform

Using Terraform v1.1.6 with Provider OCI. I would like to create a new child compartment under an **existing** parent compartment to which I only have the 'name'. For example, currently, I create a new compartment using the parent ID:

```
resource "oci_identity_compartment" "compartment" {
  compartment_id = var.compartment_id
  name           = "child_compartment"
}
```

However, I would like to do something like this, where I only know the "name" of the parent...

```
resource "oci_identity_compartment" "compartment" {
  compartment_name = "parent-name"
  name           = "child-compartment"
}
```

Is this possible? Could somehow use Terraform's data sources to look up the parent's name and return its ID, if so how?

Comment: Well, as far as I can see in the documentation, you cannot provide a name, only an id, so it doesn't seem possible. In other words, `compartment_name` is not a valid argument for the `oci_identity_compartment`.

Comment: I understand `compartment_name` is not a thing, but I was thinking maybe we can query the ID using the name from a data source?

Comment: That I think you can.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I'd like to know if you figured this out too. I am looking for a solution that allow me to lookup a resource that is in , say, compartment "production:v2.1:live". I do not want to grab the terraform remote state as it might not have the required outputs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "solution" but it is not generic and it assumes that all compartment names are unique; it is perfectly possible to have A:B:C and A:X:C which ruins what comes next.

You can use the oci data source [oci_identity_compartments](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/oracle/oci/latest/docs/data-sources/identity_compartments) to recursively list all compartment in the tenancy, that is you provide the tenancy ocid as the starting compartment_id. If you "know" that your chosen parent is unique, than you could do the following:

```
data "oci_identity_compartments" "this" {
  compartment_id = var.tenancy_ocid
  compartment_id_in_subtree = true
  name = var.my_parent_name
  state = "ACTIVE"
}
```

then you can create a new compartment thus:

```
resource "oci_identity_compartment" "this" {
  provider = oci.homeregion
  compartment_id = data.oci_identity_compartments.this.compartments[0].id
  description = "Some text"
  name = "my_compartment"
}
```

NB: you can only create compartments from your home region

But if you have identical great{1,4}child compartments, it will not work.